# Getting an error while executing the procedure from sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can any one please help

```
create or replace PROCEDURE greetings
IS
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!');
END;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any quotes in your create statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no error for syntax, but if you ask for getting a result(to message with greeting) , apply `serveroutput on` before you execute your *procedure* :

> SQL> set `serveroutput on;`
>
> SQL> exec greetings;
>
> *Hello World!*
>
> *PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.*