# Oracle DBMS_OUTPUT not returning anything if I call a specific procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a PL/SQL block I'm running that looks something like this

```
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('11');
   schema.some_package.process_data(i);
   dbms_output.put_line('22');
END;
```

When I run this block, the DBMS Output returns absolutely nothing. If I comment out the `process_data` procedure call, then it returns the 11, 22 as expected. The procedure is not raising any exceptions and appears to be processing correctly.

The `process_data` procedure does call many other procedures and too much code to share here, but does anyone have suggestions as to what I should be looking for that would be clearing ALL queued output, even output called after the procedure in my block?

Comment: please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180770/getting-an-error-while-executing-the-procedure-from-sql-developer/47181327#47181327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe would happen if something in your stack calls `dbms_output.disable()`. That suppresses all output until you call `dbms_output.enable()`.

Re-enabling output doesn't recover the suppressed output because `disable()` purges the buffer as well as disabling subsequent calls to `put_line()`, `get_line()`, etc

Comment: Thank you, this put me down the right path and I found a call to `DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE` which was the culprit.